# Composition over inheritance limits

Tags: c#, inheritance, design-patterns

I have a number of interfaces like the following:

```
public interface IFoo
{
    void FooAction();
}

public interface IBar
{
    void BarAction();
}

public interface IBiz
{
    void BizAction();
}

...others...
```

I have also defined a base abstract implementation for my interfaces. Something like this:

```
public abstract class BaseFoo() : IFoo
{
    void FooAction() { ... }
}

public abstract class BaseBar() : IBar
{
    void BarAction() { ... }
}

public abstract class BaseBiz() : IBiz
{
    void BizAction() { ... }
}

... others
```

Now I need another number of classes that implement a subset of these interfaces. Eg:

```
public class FooBar : IFoo, IBar
{
    ....
}

public class FooBiz : IFoo, IBiz
{
    ....
}

public class FooBarBiz : IFoo, IBar, IBiz
{
    ....
}
```

In a language that supports multiple inheritance I would implement the above classes inheriting from multiple abstract classes: Eg:

```
public class FooBar : BaseFoo, BaseBar, IFoo, IBar
{
    ....
}

public class FooBiz : BaseFoo, BaseBiz IFoo, IBiz
{
    ....
}

public class FooBarBiz : BaseFoo, BaseBar, BaseBiz, IFoo, IBar, IBiz
{
    ....
}
```

but this is not allowed in C#, since this kind of inheritnce is not supported.

To achieve the same result I think the approach here is to use composition over inheritance and define the classes in the following manner:

```
public class FooBar : IFoo, IBar
{
    private readonly BaseFoo Foo { get; set; } // not abstract now
    private readonly BaseBar bar { get; set; } // not abstract now

    FooBar(IFoo foo, IBar bar) // Dependency injected here
    {
        Foo = foo;
        Bar = bar;
    }

    void FooAction()
    {
        Foo.FooAction();
    }

    void BarAction()
    {
        Bar.BarAction();
    }
}
```

First of all: is this pattern correct?
A thing that makes me think something here smells is that composition over inheritance hides protected properties and field of the base classes.

Instead of composition I could also provide a base abstract class for each interfaces permutation. Eg. define a BaseFooBar, BaseFooBiz, BaseFooBarBiz, but in also in this case I find there is too much work and repetitive code.

Which is the correct approach for this kind of problem?

Comment: You are talking about composition for the _implementation_ of FooBar. That is not visible on the outside, FooBar is still using inheritance (by interface) on the outside.

Comment: To extend bommelding's comment, you've conflated some similar-but-different things (interface implemenation and inheritance). Composition over inheritance is an argument that is unrelated to using interfaces. Interfaces are a different beast altogether, even though they _can_ be used to tackle a similar issue. This makes it very hard to give you a definitive answer to your exact question, there is no "one true approach".

Comment: You could codegen your permutations (that is something that is done) but I think the composited version that implements the interfaces is actually pretty decent.